# SQL Server split value into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have strings which are delimited by `$$` characters like below:

```
BOB$$"DOG"$$"BROWN"$$"9"$$"4"$$"Latest"$$$$$$"small.
EVA$$"CAT"$$"BLACK"$$"1"$$"4"$$$$"Mouse"$$"Milk"$$small.
```

I would like to get after use functions: Update/insert into select/SSIS mapping

Table like this:

```
Column1  Column2    Column3  Column4  Column5  Column6      Column7    Column8     Column9
BOB       "DOG"     "BROWN"   "9"        "4"    "Lat,est"   NULL       NULL        small.
EVA       "CAT"     "BLACK"   "1"        "4"      NULL      "Mouse"    "Milk"      small.
```

Can I Make 9 rows with function Update/Insert into select to get the result?
I can create two tables; First table containing single column and the second table one having 9 or 10 columns.

I need universal solution for 100+ rows. The above two rows are just examples.

I think like continuing with this type of code:

```
SELECT   [Column0]
        ,LEFT([Column0], CHARINDEX('$$', [Column0]) - 1) AS [name]

FROM    [dbo].[tablename]
```

Comment: Is your data a Flat File source? Do you really intend on keeping enclosing quotes as data?

Comment: @filburt  Yes is flat file CSV but over 100 every day I use SSIS but i have problem with convert 1250 language to 1252 Visual basic studio have problem with SQL server... Easy for me i think is this way

Comment: If you are using SSIS, configuring a Flat File data source should be easy: You can set the desired Code Page and specify column delimiters `$$` as well as keeping enclosing quotes. I wouldn't expect the need for any handwritten code. If you not already tried, I'd suggest you create a Data Flow in SSIS and explore the options Flat File data source offers.

Comment: @Filburt I Try 3 all days split in SSIS / Bulk Insert HDL.fmt file but not work fine..

Comment: @Tester Are you familiar with C#? If it's a given number of Columns (10), you might want to create a C# transformation in your data flow which takes care of the splitting...

Comment: All the answers suggesting handcrafted splitting are really over-complicating things and make it much harder to maintain or add new columns. I just configured a Flat File source producing the desired pipeline data in 5 min. I strongly recommend @DhruvJoshi's Approach 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. When working with importing flat files with SSIS, we typically import everything as varchar datatype columns tables (called staging tables) and then check column values for data type consistency. 
This allows us to import everything and not lose data and gives oppertunity to clean data.

Approach 1 :**For your case you can use $$ as column delimiter in SSIS Data flow task source.**
SSIS does not care about header columns order or name. You can have anything in header names like Column 1, column 2 etc. 
in this approach you import data from file into 9 column table. This approach will fail if you have less/more columns in some rows.

Approach 2: **You import everything as single column into varchar staging table(1).** 
From here you split all columns and insert into another varchar staging table(2) of 9 columns(NULLable) and then do data validation before moving data to data typed column table.

Query that can be used in Approach 2

```
create table staging_tbl_single_row (datarow varchar(max))
insert into staging_tbl_single_row values
('BOB$$"DOG"$$"BROWN"$$"9"$$"4"$$"Latest"$$$$$$"small.'),
('EVA$$"CAT"$$"BLACK"$$"1"$$"4"$$$$"Mouse"$$"Milk"$$small.')

; with cte as 
(
    select 
    row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as column1,
    replace(datarow,'$$','|') as column2
    from staging_tbl_single_row
    )
--Insert into SomeTable 
select 
    [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9]
from 
(
    select 
        t.column1,
        split_values=SUBSTRING( t.column2, t1.N, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|',t.column2,t1.N),0)-t1.N,8000)),
        r= row_number() over( partition by column1 order by t1.N) 
    from cte t 
        join
        (
            select 
                t.column2,
                1 as N 
            from cte t  
                UNION ALL
            select 
                t.column2,
                t1.N + 1 as N
            from cte t 
                join
                (
                 select 
                    top 8000
                        row_number() over(order by (select NULL)) as N 
                 from 
                    sys.objects s1 
                        cross join 
                   sys.objects s2 
                ) t1 
            on SUBSTRING(t.column2,t1.N,1) = '|'
         ) t1
          on t1.column2=t.column2
)a
pivot
( 
    max(split_values) for r in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9])
   )p
```

<kbd>**[see working demo](http://rextester.com/NHEC54924)**</kbd>

Comment: Nice job If I want insert into table result of your select what i need to write on the start ? Insert into select ...?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.

```
;WITH CTE_1 AS (
    SELECT TXT= TXT +'$$', ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TXT) 
    FROM (VALUES
            ('BOB$$"DOG"$$"BROWN"$$"9"$$"4"$$"Lat,est"$$$$$$small.'),
            ('EVA$$"CAT"$$"BLACK"$$"1"$$"4"$$$$"Mouse"$$"Milk"$$small.')) AS X(TXT)
)
, CTE_2 AS -- It split text to rows
(
    SELECT RIGHT(CTE_1.TXT, LEN(CTE_1.TXT) - CHARINDEX('$$',CTE_1.TXT)-1) TXT , SUBSTRING(CTE_1.TXT, 0, CHARINDEX('$$',CTE_1.TXT)) WORD, CHARINDEX('$$',CTE_1.TXT) AS CI, CTE_1.ID, 1 WID 
    FROM CTE_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RIGHT(CTE_2.TXT, LEN(CTE_2.TXT) - CHARINDEX('$$',CTE_2.TXT)-1) TXT , SUBSTRING(CTE_2.TXT, 0, CHARINDEX('$$',CTE_2.TXT)) WORD, CHARINDEX('$$',CTE_2.TXT) AS CI, CTE_2.ID, WID  = WID +1
    FROM CTE_2  WHERE LEN(CTE_2.TXT) > 0
)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ID, (CASE WHEN WORD='' THEN NULL ELSE WORD END) WORD, WID FROM CTE_2 ) SRC -- It convert rows to columns by using pivot
    PIVOT(MAX(WORD) FOR WID IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9])) PVT
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Result:

```
ID                   1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8          9
-------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1                    BOB        "DOG"      "BROWN"    "9"        "4"        "Lat,est"  NULL       NULL       small.
2                    EVA        "CAT"      "BLACK"    "1"        "4"        NULL       "Mouse"    "Milk"     small.
```

Comment: I dont know how i apply your thing on my over 100rows

Comment: what is your table and column name that store the text?

Comment: For example, you can replace CTE_1 part with this 
`;WITH CTE_1 AS (
 SELECT 
  [Column0] TXT, ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Column0]) 
 FROM 
  [dbo].[tablename]
)`

Comment: Working with option (maxrecursion 0) and  same values need to be moved from column 10 to colum 13 and some from column 11 to 12

Comment: `same values need to be moved from column 10 to colum 13 and some from column 11 to 12` i don't understand this, could you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not mine, and shows a general approach

```
declare @s varchar(max) ='BOB$$DOG$$BROWN$$9$$4$$Latest$$$$small.
EVA$$CAT$$BLACK$$1$$4$$$$Mouse$$Mil$$small'

select
 t.n.value('b[1]', 'varchar(10)'),
 t.n.value('b[2]', 'varchar(10)'),
 t.n.value('b[3]', 'varchar(10)'),
 t.n.value('b[4]', 'varchar(10)'),
 t.n.value('b[5]', 'varchar(10)'),
 t.n.value('b[6]', 'varchar(10)'),
 t.n.value('b[7]', 'varchar(10)'),
 t.n.value('b[8]', 'varchar(10)') 

from
 (select cast(cast('' as xml).query('sql:variable("@s")') as varchar(max))) a(s) cross apply
 (select cast('<a><b>' + replace(replace(a.s, '$$', '</b><b>'), '.', '</b></a><a><b>') + '</b></a>' as xml)) b(x) cross apply
 b.x.nodes('a') t(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following a simple C# example, which can easily be transformed into a C# transformation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] MyInput = new string[]{"BOB$$\"DOG\"$$\"BROWN\"$$\"9\"$$\"4\"$$\"Latest\"$$$$ß\"small."
                                         , "EVA$$\"CAT\"$$\"BLACK\"$$\"1\"$$\"4\"$$$$\"Mouse\"$$\"Milk\"small."};
            int InputIndex = 0;

            string[] delimiters = new string[]{"$$"};

            foreach (string si in MyInput)
            {
                string OutCol01 = null, OutCol02 = null, OutCol03 = null, OutCol04 = null, OutCol05 = null
                     , OutCol06 = null, OutCol07 = null, OutCol08 = null, OutCol09 = null, OutCol10 = null;

                int ColIdx = 0;

                InputIndex += 1;

                string[] x = si.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.None);

                foreach (string s in x)
                {
                    ColIdx += 1;

                    switch (ColIdx)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            OutCol01 = s;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            OutCol02 = s;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            OutCol03 = s;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            OutCol04 = s;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            OutCol05 = s;
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            OutCol06 = s;
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            OutCol07 = s;
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            OutCol08 = s;
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            OutCol09 = s;
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            OutCol10 = s;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(InputIndex.ToString() + " - " + OutCol01);
                Console.WriteLine(InputIndex.ToString() + " - " + OutCol02);
                Console.WriteLine(InputIndex.ToString() + " - " + OutCol03);
                Console.WriteLine(InputIndex.ToString() + " - " + OutCol04);
                Console.WriteLine(InputIndex.ToString() + " - " + OutCol05);
                Console.WriteLine(InputIndex.ToString() + " - " + OutCol06);
                Console.WriteLine(InputIndex.ToString() + " - " + OutCol07);
                Console.WriteLine(InputIndex.ToString() + " - " + OutCol08);
                Console.WriteLine(InputIndex.ToString() + " - " + OutCol09);
                Console.WriteLine(InputIndex.ToString() + " - " + OutCol10);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try if you have `fix 9 Column Data` :

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN Column1 = ''
           THEN NULL
           ELSE Column1
       END Column1,
       CASE
           WHEN Column2 = ''
           THEN NULL
           ELSE Column2
       END Column2,
       CASE
           WHEN Column3 = ''
           THEN NULL
           ELSE Column3
       END Column3,
       CASE
           WHEN Column4 = ''
           THEN NULL
           ELSE Column4
       END Column4,
       CASE
           WHEN Column5 = ''
           THEN NULL
           ELSE Column5
       END Column5,
       CASE
           WHEN Column6 = ''
           THEN NULL
           ELSE Column6
       END Column6,
       CASE
           WHEN Column7 = ''
           THEN NULL
           ELSE Column7
       END Column7,
       CASE
           WHEN Column8 = ''
           THEN NULL
           ELSE Column8
       END Column8,
       CASE
           WHEN Column9 = ''
           THEN NULL
           ELSE Column9
       END Column9
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           Split.a.value('/M[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') Column1,
           Split.a.value('/M[2]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') Column2,
           Split.a.value('/M[3]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') Column3,
           Split.a.value('/M[4]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') Column4,
           Split.a.value('/M[5]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') Column5,
           Split.a.value('/M[6]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') Column6,
           Split.a.value('/M[7]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') Column7,
           Split.a.value('/M[8]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') Column8,
           Split.a.value('/M[9]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') Column9
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CAST('<M>'+REPLACE(<Column>, '$$', '</M><M>')+'</M>' AS XML) AS String
        FROM <table_name>
    ) A
    CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/M') Split(a)
) A;
```

**Desired Output :**

```
Column1  Column2    Column3  Column4  Column5  Column6      Column7    Column8     Column9
BOB       "DOG"     "BROWN"   "9"        "4"    "Lat,est"      NULL      NULL       small.
EVA       "CAT"     "BLACK"   "1"        "4"      NULL      "Mouse"     "Milk"     small.
```

Comment: Msg 9421, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: line 1, character 880, illegal name character

Comment: @Tester shw ur query attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Although you already accepted a different solution I'd like to show how to solve this the SSIS way with absolutely no coding required:

**1)** If not already present, add a **Data Flow** element to your Package Control Flow.

**2)** Go to the Data Flow and add a **Flat File Source** element.

**3)** Click to edit the Flat File Source.

- On the **Connection Manager** pane, mark the checkbox **"Retain null values from the source as null values in the data flow"**
- click the **New...** button to create a new Flat File Connection.

**4)** On the **Flat File Connection Manager Editor**, click **Browse...** to open your source file.

- Select the desired Code Page / Encoding
- Leave the pre-selected default values for **Format**, **Text qualifier**, **Header row delimiter** and **Header rows to skip**
- Uncheck **"Column names in the first data row"** (unless other than your example, your real files contain a header row)

**5)** Switch to the **Columns** pane and change the **Column delimiter** to `$$` (just type in - the listed values are just proposed as a selection of the most commonly used)

- click the **Refresh** button to see your columns getting recognized to way you expect.

**6)** Switch to the **Advanced** pane.

- selected every single column in the left Listbox and edit the **Name** property to a meaningful value
- Modify the value for **OutputColumnWidth** where needed.
- select all columns in the left Listbox and mass-edit the **TextQualified** to `False` ... this will make sure your surrounding quotes are kept as desired.
- Switch to the **Preview** pane to check and close the Flat File Connection Editor with **OK**.

**7)** Close the Flat File Source Editor with **OK**.

**8)** Add the desired Destination (OLE DB) and connect your Flat File Source